# *** glibc detected *** free(): invalid next size (normal): 0x0a03c978 ***

Tags: c, linux, sockets, gcc

I'm writing a socket program to download images. The problem is that when I test my code on small pics like gif it works fine. But when I run it with JPG pics (bigger than GIF) I got the error message:

```
*** glibc detected *** /home/ubuntu/NetBeansProjects/myDownloader/dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/mydownloader: free(): invalid next size (normal): 0x0a03c978 ***
```

Please see the code and I'll give more information about the error.

```
FILE* pFile;
long lSize;
unsigned char* buffer;
size_t result;
FILE* combinedFile = fopen("mypic.jpg", "wb+");

for(i = 1; i <= numberOfPartitions; i++)
{
    sprintf(filename, "part%d", i);
    pFile = fopen(filename, "rb");

    //obtain file size
    fseek(pFile , 0 , SEEK_END);
    lSize = ftell(pFile);
    rewind(pFile);

    // allocate memory to contain the whole file:
    buffer = (unsigned char*) malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * (lSize + 1));

    if(buffer == NULL)
    {
        fputs("Memory error", stderr);
        exit(2);
    }

    // copy the file into the buffer:
    result = fread(buffer, 1, lSize, pFile);

    if(result != lSize)
    {
        fputs("Reading error", stderr);
        exit(3);
    }
    else
    {
        unsigned char* temp = strstr(buffer, "\r\n\r\n");

        temp = temp + 4;
        int len = lSize - (temp - buffer);

        //printf("i :  %d len is : %d plen is %f\n",i,len,pLen);
        if(i != numberOfPartitions)
            fwrite(temp, 1, len - 1, combinedFile);
        else
            fwrite(temp, 1, len, combinedFile);
    }

    fclose(pFile);
    printf("crash here\n");
    free(buffer);

}

fclose(combinedFile);
```

I got the error from this part, as i said when the image size is small it works fine. But with bigger size it's broken! 
P.S: The program divided the pic into several files then re-combine it so the combining part is the one that causes the error.

Any help will be very much appreciated since I've been stuck with this error for more than 3 days!

Comment: The only thing that jumps out at me is `strstr(buffer,"\r\n\r\n");`.  Why are you searching for (Windows-style) return characters in a binary file?

Comment: to determine the end of the header that come with the response through the socket. This is the onlyway to discard this header and start copying the binary data.

Comment: When there are multiple "partitions", do all such "partitions" include the `"\r\n\r\n"` sequence?

Comment: Are you processing a chunked HTTP response?  I think @pmg is right, only the first chunk has header, so later `temp` is NULL and your calculations are wrong.

Comment: hi, Actually each partition has been generated by executing a different GET request. So, each of them include  "\r\n\r\n". The problem happen when the loop finish the first iteration when it arrives to free(buffer) it crashes!

Comment: FYI, [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/), which is probably available in your distribution's package manager, is a great tool to help with this type of thing.

Comment: I ran Valgrind but I couldn't understand its output!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't verify that the `fopen()` calls all succeed; this is a recipe for trouble.

You don't check the `ftell()` gives you a plausible value in `lSize`.

You don't verify that the `strstr()` operation actually finds the marker string.  If it doesn't, it will return NULL and the following length operations are then bogus.  But the error suggests that your code has written out of bounds, rather than just read data out of bounds.

You could declare the first four variables into the body of the loop instead of outside the loop.

You don't show the declaration of the variable `filename`; could that be a char pointer with no space allocated?  Or is it an array that is big enough?

It is an odds-on bet that something has written beyond the end of some allocated space.  It is not immediately obvious that there's anything wrong with this code, but the trouble could be elsewhere yet it is this code that suffers the effects of transgressions elsewhere.  This is quite common with memory problems; the code that finds the problem isn't the code that causes it.

Does the `malloc()` on your machine return null or a non-null pointer when you allocate zero bytes?  Both are legitimate responses.

If `ftell()` returns -1, then `malloc()` would allocate a buffer for 0 bytes, but the `fread()` would attempt to read up to 4 GB of data, which might overflow the space.  OTOH, if `ftell()` fails, it is likely that `fread()` will fail too.

Have you printed out the sizes of the files?  Is it the second partial file that crashes, or a later file?

---

I've taken the code you supplied, wrapped it up as a `main()` function, supplied missing variables and headers, and run it under valgrind.  (MacOS X 10.6.6, GCC 4.5.2, Valgrind 3.6.0)  It shows no problem.  So, your trouble is most probably not in this code per se; something else earlier in your program trampled out of bounds of allocated memory and caused this to fail.  I generated the 4 part files using the script:

`{ echo "Header:control-Vcontrol-Mreturncontrol-Vcontrol-M";
  dd if=/dev/random bs=1k count=4; } >part1`

So each file was 4107 bytes long.

#### Working Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char filename[32];
    FILE* pFile;
    long lSize;
    char *buffer;
    ssize_t result;
    FILE* combinedFile = fopen("mypic.jpg", "wb+");
    int numberOfPartitions = 4;
    int i;

    for(i = 1; i <= numberOfPartitions; i++)
    {
        sprintf(filename, "part%d", i);
        pFile = fopen(filename, "rb");

        fseek(pFile , 0 , SEEK_END);
        lSize = ftell(pFile);
        rewind(pFile);
        printf("size(%d) = %ld\n", i, lSize);

        buffer = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * (lSize + 1));

        if (buffer == NULL)
        {
            fputs("Memory error", stderr);
            exit(2);
        }

        result = fread(buffer, 1, lSize, pFile);

        if (result != lSize)
        {
            fputs("Reading error", stderr);
            exit(3);
        }
        else
        {
            char* temp = strstr(buffer, "\r\n\r\n");    
            temp = temp + 4;
            int len = lSize - (temp - buffer);
            if(i != numberOfPartitions)
                fwrite(temp, 1, len - 1, combinedFile);
            else
                fwrite(temp, 1, len, combinedFile);
        }

        fclose(pFile);
        printf("crash here\n");
        free(buffer);    
    }

    fclose(combinedFile);
    return 0;
}
```

I've not inserted all the error checking that I would if it were my own program.

The output file in my scheme is 16381 bytes long; that is 3 bytes short.  The problem there is the `fwrite()` calls.  The `fread()` code told you how many bytes it read; you subtracted the bytes for the header, and then subtracted one more.  So, that `if/else` code reduces to just the `fwrite()` in the `else`.

Comment: hi, all the partitions has data with size more than 1. it works when i move free(buffer) out of the loop but crashes after about 17 iterations.my machine returns null when malloc allocates zero bytes. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Hi, Thanx for your effort to help fixing this bug. I'm sorry for bothering you but I've sent you an email to ur gmail account with the complete program to find out if other parts of my code causes this problem. Again thank you very much for your help.

Comment: The problem was not in the code shown; it was in code allocating space for messages to send over the internet.  Changing '-6' into '+32' for the allocation size cured the 'write out of bounds' and everything else worked magically.  It leaked a lot of memory.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I can't find anything obviously wrong with your memory or file handling in the code above, the crash on free() might just be a symptom of something in your code writing into malloc()'s personal space...

You could use memory checkers such as Valgrind or debuggers like gdb to take a closer look.

The only possibly wrong thing that comes to mind is that buffer is not necessarily NUL-terminated, and as such the strstr() search can happily go over it, buffer[lSize] = '\0'; after the malloc-NULL-check should fix that. Also just to be sure, check that strstr() actually found what it was looking for (it returns NULL if it didn't). You may also want to check that all your fopen() calls actually succeed (return not NULL).
If none of this helps, printout's of len, lSize, temp and buffer's values just before the fwrite() calls would be helpful.

Comment: I've tried buffer[lSize]='\0' but nothing changes!!! When I moved free(buffer) out of the loop it works fine till iteration number 17 out of 20 then it crashes! this means the whole problem is with memory allocation, don't u think so?